# How to push_back in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I made a class as follows:

```
class Variable {
public:
  string name;
  double value;
};
```

Used it to make a vector as follows:

```
vector<Variable> var_table;
```

Then I made a function is_declared to check whether the given string name is already present the var_table or not and made another function define_name to put value of a string and a double into name and value of a new variable in var_table as follows:

```
bool is_declared(string var) {
  for (int i = 0; i < var_table.size(); ++i)
    if (var_table[i].name == var)
      return true;
  return false;
}

double define_name(string var, double val) {
  if (is_declared(var))
    cerr << var << "declared twice";
  var_table.push_back(Variable{var, val});
  return val;
}
```

In the line

```
var_table.push_back(Variable{var,val});
```

it shows the following error:

> 238 expected primary-expression before '{' token

Please help!!!

Comment: Are you using a compiler that supports the C++11 standard or higher?

Comment: You need a compiler that supports C++11.

Comment: Judging from the two functions you posted, a `std::map<string,double>` could be more suited than a `std::vector<Variable>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use initializer syntax with C++ compiler below level of compliance C++11. You have to use `Variable(var,val)` to make it possibly work, or compile code with newer compiler.

Small note - have you considered use `set` for such a task?

Answer (score -1):

First thing is you need to provide a constructor in your Variable class to instantiate the values to variables.

and next, in the line,

```
var_table.push_back(Variable{var,val});
```

you can write as,

```
var_table.push_back(Variable(var,val));
```

Comment: You don't need a constructor at all, and the braces initialization is valid and preferred.